# What is the difference between the rated and withstand Voltage?

Tags: voltage, common-mode-choke

In case of a **common mode choke**,

I have seen in two different component manufacturers these two terms:

- rated voltage
- withstand voltage

Are they the same? How are they related?

Comment: Can you give an example (link to a datasheet) of a choke part that specifies "withstand voltage"? That's a spec I'd think is more likely to see on things like switches or esd protection diodes.

Comment: I saw it on the murata datasheet [link](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/emiconfun/mail/2012/08/28/en-20120828/l0132s0197dlw43s.ashx?la=en)

Answer (score 2):

The withstand voltage is explained in the [specification sheet](http://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdata/8796758605854/QFLC9101.pdf) for your part:

[image]

The withstand voltage is the maximum voltage where the manufacturer guarantees less than 1 mA leakage current and no damage to the part if it is applied for up to 5 s.

The "rated voltage" is 40% of the withstand voltage. Probably they intend the rated voltage to be the maximum nominal operating voltage for the part.

Comment: +1 Nice link. There does not seem to be a spec on the common mode voltage across the chokes, just the voltage between them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, The part doesn't seem to contain anything electrically connected to anything other than the two coils, so they can't really own that.

Comment: Suppose there's a common mode spike on the pair, it's supposed to have significant voltage across it to kill the spike - that's its  job. They don't tell us how much is too much for the wire insulation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, fair point.

Answer (score 1):

Rated Voltage is the maximum recommended voltage at which you should operate. Operating at voltage above rated voltage will not yield desired results (not necessarily destroy the device).

Withstand voltage is like **Point of no return**, after which the device will be permanently damaged.